# Global Pointer in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-data, singly-linked-list

So I have this problem and I was hoping you could help me with it. I have this linked list and the user is asked to input data in it. It works for when I use only one set but I want this linked list to work with more than 1 set but I have declared the head node as global and I don't know how to arrange it. The problem is that when I input data in a set it is keeping that input for the second set as well.

This is the structure of the linked list:

```
struct node//initializing a linked list
{
    int info;
    struct node*link;
}*start;
```

This is how I created my linked list:

```
list* createList()
{
    struct node*set;
    set=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        set->link=NULL;
        start=set;
    }
    return set;
}
```

and finally this is the Add function:

```
list* Add(list* set,int x)
{
    struct node *tempnode;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation failed. Goodbye!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    set=start;
    printf("Please enter an input: \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while(1)
    {
        while(x==set->info)
        {
            printf("Error! Please enter another integer: \n");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            set=start;
        }
        if(set->link!=NULL)
        set=set->link;
        else
            break;
    }
    tempnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tempnode->info=x;
    tempnode->link=NULL;
    set->link=tempnode;
    printf("%d was created successfully!\n",x);
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Well, every function that currently operates on the global variable will need to be modified to operate on an argument instead.

Comment: yes, but can you give me some tips as to how to change them please?

Answer (score 1):

As Oli Charlesworth already commented, you need to pass the list you want to operate on as an argument to every function that deals with a list. I'll show you how in a second, but let me comment on some issues with your code first.

- Your code looks untidy, because you don't separate the logic of the
  set (add number, check whether number is already in the set) from the
  input (everything to do with `scanf`). Instead you `Add` function
  implements everything in a big chunk.
- Also, why do you pass `x` as an argument to `Add`? It is never read
  (not after being overwritten by `scanf` at least). This should really
  be a local variable. The same goes for `set`, which you use as local
  variable at the moment.
- You have typedef'fed `struct node` to `list`, which is legit,
  but a bit confusing. (A node is not the list.)

Okay, onward to your question: You should create a `start = NULL` for every new list. Then you pass that `start` to all list functions. But you have to be careful here: Most functions - like printing or checking whether a number is in the list - don't change the value of `start`. You addition function must change it, so you should pass `&start`, i.e. a `struct node **` to such functions.

Because that's a bit confusing, you can use an alternative solution: Create a struct that represents a list, write a creator function for that list and then operatoe on a pointer of that struct.

Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Set Set;
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int info;
    Node *next;
};

struct Set {
    Node *head;
};

Set *set_create()
{
    Set *set = malloc(sizeof(*set));

    // enforce set != NULL
    set->head = NULL;
    return set;
}

void set_delete(Set *set)
{
    Node *node = set->head;

    while (node) {
        Node *next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
}

int set_contains(const Set *set, int x)
{
    const Node *node = set->head;

    while (node) {
        if (node->info == x) return 1;
        node = node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void set_print(const Set *set)
{
    const Node *node = set->head;

    printf("{");
    while (node) {
        if (node != set->head) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", node->info);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

Node *set_add(Set *set, int x)
{
    Node *node;

    if (set_contains(set, x)) return NULL;

    node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    // enforce node != NULL

    node->info = x;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (set->head == NULL) {
        set->head = node;
    } else {
        Node *iter = set->head;

        while (iter->next) iter = iter->next;
        iter->next = node;
    }

    return node;
}

int main()
{
    Set *one = set_create();
    Set *two = set_create();

    set_add(one, 1);
    set_add(one, 1);
    set_add(one, 2);
    set_add(one, 3);
    set_add(one, 5);
    set_add(one, 1);
    set_add(one, 5);

    set_add(two, 1);
    set_add(two, 2);
    set_add(two, 4);

    set_print(one);
    set_print(two);

    set_delete(one);
    set_delete(two);

    return 0;
}
```

There are several things to note:

- The code is split up into small functions that do a specific task. They may call each other and it is alway clear what is done.
- The constructor function `set_create` creates a pointer to an empty list. That pointer is your *handle*  that you should pass as first parameter to all list functions.
- As in your code, the function to add integers checks whether the list already contains the integer. Because the `set_add` function does not deal with input from the user, however, it signals whetherv a node has really been added or not in its return value: It is `NULL` if the integer was already in the list, a pointer to the new node otherwise.
- When you create a list and add integers to it, you allocate memory with `malloc`. That means, that you also need to have a function that releases the memory again with `free`, so that you can avoid memory leaks.
- The example code adds some hard-wired integers to the list; it does not deal with user input. You can easily write a loop to add elements in your `main` function and then add them.
- Because the handle to the list is a struct, you can easily extend the list interface by adding new fields to that struct. For example, you might want to keep a count of nodes or a flag that indicates whether the nodes are sorted.